# Word meaning "analyze" and "make a decision"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

I'm searching the word that describes both "analyze" and "make a decision." I want to use it as the name of a process.

**Edit:**

I would like a word that encapsulates the meaning of:

- Analyze options
- Choose one (make the decision)

**Edit 2:**

It will be a process done by a software.

Comment: It would be good if you could show us an example of where you would use it. I am sure this will boost our creativity : )

Comment: according to this accepted answer http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6431/what-is-the-difference-between-make-decision-and-take-decision you want the translation of 'make a decision'. Please let us know if this is correct and provide an example of the intended use.

Comment: Apparently, "making a decision" is what I'm looking for. What would be am appropriate translation?

Comment: I think that `actualizar` would envelope the phrase you're looking for.

Comment: Also, the verb *decidir* itself can mean both, depending on the aspect: *el juez decidía el caso* (lo estaba contemplando, he was deciding/deliberating), y *el juez decidió el caso* (emitió su dictamen, he decided it / issued his judgment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**determinar** significa, según el DRAE (23.ª ed.), a la vez y en forma no pronominal, *discernir* y *tomar resolución*.

Comment: y funciona perfectamente para una rutina de software.

Comment: Si, al parecer esta es la palabra más apropriada hasta ahora.

Answer (score 1):

May be the word [deliberar](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=nafxziFaEDXX2aDs9WMP%7CVTiuSoMaIDXX2zAFIzUi), but I'm not sure it can be used with both directions simultaneously.

> Estamos felices porque el jurado deliberó a nuestro favor.

Comment: Deliberar no incluye la toma de la decision. Es solo el proceso para llegar a ella. La decision final es el **veredicto**.  _Estamos felices porque el jurado emitió un veredicto favorable_  [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?key=veredicto)

Comment: Tienes razón, y por eso mi duda. Pero mira la segunda acepción que da la RAE (en el link). Entonces el ejemplo que pongo sirve tanto para "consideró" como para "resolvió".

Comment: Excelente propuesta. Originariamente era el proceso de análisis, pero se empieza a usar como entrega de los resultados del análisis (sí, veredicto). Curiosamente (por azar, imagino) tiene un símil con "delivery", que es entrega. Quizás @Christian podría mezclarlo para nombrar el proceso.

Comment: Excellent proposal. Originally it refers to the analysis process, but nowadays it's being used as the delivering of the end results of that analysis (yes, "veredicto"). Strangely, it looks similar to "delivery" (the English word). Maybe @Christian could mix them to name the process.

Comment: I don't think "deliberar" is appropriate in my case. It will be a process done by a software.

Answer (score 0):

How about "**discriminar**"?

It's my best guess, in its meaning of: "determinar, precisar, definir."

Some others that may come close to parts of the whole process could be:

"Tamizar"

"Discernir"

"ponderar"

"filtrar" or "cribar"

"evaluar"

"precisar"

Comment: Mmmm, nope. I don't think any are useful in my case. Let me know if there is something I should specify better.

Comment: Lol, ok. No, I don't think there's anything you could precise better. The difficulty lies in the concept. Both parts (analyze and decide) are mutually exclusive, uhmm, are "brainly" of different nature, lol, I don't know how to say that. For sure there must be at least one word, but it's a challenge to find it.

Comment: Answering this question is starting to metaphorically illustrate your process itself. : ))

Comment: I know what you mean... Maybe we should create a new word :P

Comment: LOL. I vote for "Analicidir"

Answer (score 0):

In software engineering, this is represented by a "[diagrama de flujo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/76/DiagramaFlujoLampara.svg/220px-DiagramaFlujoLampara.svg.png)". Maybe you can call the process "flujo"